# pandas "2D rank" dataframe into (row,col) indices tuples

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix, rank

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(4,3))

          0         1         2
0 -1.122880 -2.662009  1.180418
1 -0.335768  0.162640  0.105928
2 -1.282813  0.049638  1.532208
3 -0.422884 -1.110049  0.031648
```

Looking for a function (`get_ranks(data)`?) that will return an ordered set of (row, col) tuples. So for the above:
   (2,2), (0,2), (3,2), (1,1), ...

Working with a huge dataset and am trying to efficiently return tuples that rank the elements of the DataFrame. Tried a few awkward sequences of `apply()`, `rank()` and such but want something nicer.

I searched around a bunch but haven't found commentary applying to this in particular. Should I just cat the rows or cols together and rank it from there? Or is there a more direct path?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of operations on the huge dataset, it may make sense to keep it in 'stacked form', then unstack later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3))                                                                      
>>> df
          0         1         2
0  1.644294  1.476467 -0.137539
1 -0.448040 -0.329539 -0.996425
2 -1.015308 -1.397746  0.369095
3 -0.570194 -0.989716 -1.489257
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten())
>>> df2
           0
0   1.644294
1   1.476467
2  -0.137539
3  -0.448040
4  -0.329539
5  -0.996425
6  -1.015308
7  -1.397746
8   0.369095
9  -0.570194
10 -0.989716
11 -1.489257
>>> df3 = df2.rank()
>>> df3['row'] = df3.index % 4
>>> df3['column'] = (df3.index/4).astype(int)                                                                    
>>> df3
       0  row  column
0   12.0    0       0
1   11.0    1       0
2    9.0    2       0
3    7.0    3       0
4    8.0    0       1
5    4.0    1       1
6    3.0    2       1
7    2.0    3       1
8   10.0    0       2
9    6.0    1       2
10   5.0    2       2
11   1.0    3       2
```

Some explanations :

I flatten the original DataFrame, and then use `rank()` to get the rank of the values in the flattened array.
I then use modulo and division operations to get the original position of the value.

The resulting DataFrame has 3 columns : the first one is the rank of the value (12 -> max, 1 -> min), the second one is the index of the original row of the value, and the third is the index of the original column of the value.

Hope it'll be helpful, and please let me know if it's not entirely clear.

Comment: wow, yes, thanks. was working with something like but definitely not as straightforward

Answer (score 1):

`stack` your dataframe, then `sort_values` with `ascending=False`, then take `index.tolist()`

```
data.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist()
```